# How many words B2 level of German Language contain?

Tags: vocabulary

During December 2018, i failed in writing exam from Goethe Institute and my failure appeared in writing component. I need to know how many words B2 level contains in German Language.

Comment: I guess your teacher or the exam institute will tell you what your vocabulary needs to be to pass.

Comment: The best advice for you is: work through the materials your school (Goethe Institute, or whoever) recommends you. If you find an unknown word, try to memorize it, ideally in context. - This is the better approach than trying to learn lists of words. - Some materials can be found here: https://www.goethe.de/en/spr/kup/prf/prf/gb2/ue9.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For instance, the university of Dresden says(<sup>[1](https://linguistik.zih.tu-dresden.de/lehre/blogs/wortschatzingrammatiken/didaktische-grundlagen/wortschatzgroesse/)</sup>):

- A1     600
- A2    1200
- B1    2500
- B2    3000
- C1-C2 4000-6000